# Screenshot of ADInterstitialAd programmatically in iOS gives black image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, iad

When I show the iAd on `_parentView(UIView)` and create the image of this `_parentView`.

I show this image (resultingImage) on a `UIImageView`, then this image is blank(totally black).

How can I get the screenshot of `iAd` programmatically?

```
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)currentView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _parentView = currentView;
        self.interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
   [interstitialAd presentInView:_parentView];
   [self takeScreenshot];
}

- (void)takeScreenshot
{
    CGRect      rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _parentView.frame.size.width, _parentView.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [_parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Now i hope for at least one comment towards my problem. If anyone have any idea about that, then please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the device is a iPad?
Based on the [Official Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html).

It seems like you are doing it correctly. You might wana check if

```
  [interstitialAd presentInView:_parentView];
```

returns a true of false, before continuing.

If that does not help, try using the delegate function:

```
- (void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

if it returns you any errors.

Edit:
Try using the root view controller from the key window. It works for me.

```
if([self.interstitial presentInView:_view])
{ NSLog(@"Able to present in view"); }
else
{ [self.interstitial presentFromViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController]; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest but it is not the answer that i was looking for. My iAd shows properly but the thing is that i want to take the screenshot after present the iAd on currentView(UIVIew) and it gives me back blank image. Please try to implement it at your end also. Thanks for your answer.